# BattleGrounds reward for win

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

If BattleGround is won by an alliance, all players in the alliance (on BG) will receive a `305047` item.
If a horde wins a BattleGround, all players in the hordes (on BG) receive a `305048` item.

These are the items of the award chests. Can you tell me how to do this?

Maybe it can be done in LUA using [Eluna](http://elunaluaengine.github.io/)?

```
if (player->GetTeamId(TEAM_HORDE))
    player->AddItem(305047, 1);
else
    player->AddItem(305048, 1);
```

upd2: This code works but not correctly. It gives out awards everywhere. At Arena and BG. I need the award to be given only on BG.

Comment: its my first question for this problem :/

Comment: Ok. Im change ..

Comment: Nice. 2 dislikes for my question.
Thanks

Comment: OK. Im change now my question. Would somebody please help me

Comment: so you're making your own azerothcore build or what? imagine that maybe 1 of 10000 users here knows what azerothcore is in the first place. so if you want help you might want to add more information on what you're actually doing

Comment: I took a good kernel AzerothCore and want to make my changes for custom server there

Comment: can't you use player->InBattleground() to check if the player is in BattleGround? Thats something I found in the source within a minute. Just a guess

Comment: ```if (player->InBattleground() || player->GetTeamId(TEAM_HORDE))```
?

Comment: @doka2trade while it might be obvious to some that you are using the Eluna Lua Engine (that is an addition to AzerothCore which otherwise would be C++ only), it might not be for others. So I've update your question including a reference to it, so everyone can check its API and help you

Comment: Question not solved

Comment: a) it's Lua, without screaming. b) this is stackoverflow, not specific-wow-addon-library-discussion, so maybe give us some background on what you actually want instead of throwing a bunch of ingame terms and 3 lines of nonworking code in our faces.

Answer (score 3):

```php
if (!isArena()) {
  if (bgTeamId == winnerTeamId) {
    if (TEAM_ALLIANCE == winnerTeamId) {
      player->AddItem(XXXXX, 1); // Here add Item for Alliance players to get on BG End
    } else {
      if (TEAM_HORDE == winnerTeamId) {
        player->AddItem(XXXXX, 1); // Here add Item For Horde players to get on BG end
      }
    }
  }
```

Then just use that

Answer (score 2):

```
local H2Item = ;
local A2Item = ;

local function onBattlegroundEnd(event, bg, bgId, instanceId, winner)
    for k, player in ipair(GetPlayersInWorld()) do
        if player:GetInstanceId() == instanceId then
            if winner == 1 and player:IsHorde() == 1 then
                player:AddItem(H2Item)
            elseif winner == 0 and player:IsHorde() == 0 then
                player:AddItem(A2Item)
            end
        end
    end
end
RegisterBGEvent(2, onBattlegroundEnd)
```

It's ok for this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with C++, editing existing file battleground.cpp and at the line 985 use this:

```
if (bgTeamId == winnerTeamId)
    {
        if (TEAM_ALLIANCE == winnerTeamId)
            player->AddItem(XXXXX, 1); // Here add Item for Alliance players to get on BG End
        else
            if (TEAM_HORDE == winnerTeamId)
            {
                player->AddItem(XXXXX, 1); // Here add Item For Horde players to get on BG end
            }
```

Comment: im check this. Reward items for win on BG - ok
But
Reward also add for arenas win :(
Its bad
I need only BG.